# Bitarrays with Text in between

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, nodes, arrays

i am very new to Latex, i want to draw Bitarrays, while i got it working (in a very inelegant way) in beamer i struggle to get it properly working in article. I copied an example from some code on this website and just changed it to get my result, i am not sure if i actually know what i am doing.

What i want:

1. Draw Bitarrays, have the equation/operation on the left of it
2. Put some text between the Bitarrays(to explain the Operation i just performed)
3. Align all Bitarrays properly
4. Draw a bracelet on the right side and put a number on it (like in Picture 2)
5. In my document i have used `\footnotesize` (see picture 2) Is there a better way to *automatically* adjust the size and have the same size for all boxes/texts/equations within this `tikzpicture`?
6. I want to colour every bit that is 1, is there an automatic way to do it instead of colouring every single node?

What i have done so far:

For beamer i solved it with making every single bit a node. This is very inelegant, resulted in way too much code and now i struggle with putting text in between.

For example the following code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

 \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix, arrows.meta,calc,positioning,chains,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}

\oddsidemargin=0.in
\topmargin=-1.5cm
\textheight=23cm
\textwidth=16cm

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  %-{Stealth[length = 2.5pt]},
       start chain = going right,
     node distance = 0pt,
MyStyle/.style={draw, minimum width=1mm, minimum height=2mm,
                outer sep=0pt, on chain},
  ]
 \node [MyStyle] (L1) {$ x_{1}$};       %
\node [MyStyle, right=1.7cm of L1] (R1) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (2) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (3) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (4) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (5) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (6) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (7) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (8) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (9) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (11) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (12) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (13) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (14) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (15) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (16) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (17) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (18) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (19) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (20) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (21) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle, fill=green!50] (22) {$1$};
\node [MyStyle] (23) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (24) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle, fill=green!50] (25) {$1$};
\node [MyStyle, fill=green!50] (26) {$1$};
\node [MyStyle] (27) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle, fill=green!50] (28) {$1$};
\node [MyStyle] (29) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (30) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle, fill=green!50] (31) {$1$};
\node [MyStyle] (RE1) {$0$}; 
\node[on chain]            {  };


\node [MyStyle, below=0.4cm of L1] (L2) {$x^{(1)}_{1}= x_{1} \gg (32-2)$};   %
\node [MyStyle, below=0.5cm of R1] (R2) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (35) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (36) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (37) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (38) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (39) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (40) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (41) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (42) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (43) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (44) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (45) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (46) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (47) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (48) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (49) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (50) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (51) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (52) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (53) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (54) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (55) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (56) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (57) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (58) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (59) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (60) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (61) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (62) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (63) {$0$};
\node [MyStyle] (RE2) {$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which results in picture 1:

[image: Picture 1]

Picture 2: As you can see its not aligned, i would like to avoid to manually align this for every beginning node.

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

Perhaps this could be a start point. I created a `\pic` for the bit arrays and adjusted the scale of the `tikzpicture` to fit in the article geometry (you'll probably need to change the scale). The bracket is drawn with the help of `decorations` library, and the align is made by hand but it's not very difficult.

My code:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage    {amssymb} % \gg \veebar
\usepackage    {lipsum}  % dummy text
\usepackage    {tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % decoration, brace

\tikzset
{%
    my label/.style={draw,inner sep=1pt},
    my arrow/.style={red,->},
    my brace/.style={red,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=1mm}},
    pics/bitarray/.style={% #1 = list of bits
      code={%
        \foreach[count=\j from 0]\i in {#1}
        {
          \ifnum\i>0
            \fill[green] (0.5*\j,0) rectangle ++ (0.5,0.5);
          \fi
          \draw (0.5*\j,0) rectangle ++ (0.5,0.5);
          \node at (0.5*\j+0.25,0.25) {$\i$};
        }
        \coordinate (-west)       at (0,0.25);
        \coordinate (-north east) at (16,0.5);
        \coordinate (-south east) at (16,0);
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,scale=0.59] % <-- change the scale if you have other paper geometry
%\draw[help lines] (-3,0) grid[step=0.5] (16,7);% <-- only to see positions and alignment
% bit arrays
\pic (1) at (0,6) {bitarray={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0}};
\pic (2) at (0,4) {bitarray={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
\pic (3) at (0,2) {bitarray={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
\pic (4) at (0,0) {bitarray={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1}};
% labels
\node[my label] (A) at (-2,6.25) {\strut $y = x_1$};
\node[my label] (B) at (-2,5.25) {\strut $y^{(1)} = y \gg 11$};
\node[my label] (C) at (-2,3.25) {\strut $y^{(2)} = y^{(1)} \& d$};
\node[my label] (D) at (-2,1.25) {\strut $y^{(3)} = y \veebar y^{(2)}$};
% bracket
\draw[my brace] (1-north east) -- (4-south east) node[black,midway,xshift=8mm]{$(1.1)$};
% optional arrows
\draw[my arrow] (A) -- (1-west);
\draw[my arrow] ([yshift=-1mm]1-west) to[bend right] (B.east) to[bend right] ([yshift=1mm]2-west); 
\draw[my arrow] ([yshift=-1mm]2-west) to[bend right] (C.east) to[bend right] ([yshift=1mm]3-west); 
\draw[my arrow] ([yshift=-1mm]3-west) to[bend right] (D.east) to[bend right] ([yshift=1mm]4-west); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some bit arrays.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]